# Show/hide text using getElementsByClassName for all classes

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

I am trying to show/hide text with the same class.  I tried the following code that hides only the first id `getElementById`, which makes me decide to remove all `IDs` and just keep the `class`.

The text/words to be hidden are in different positions in the page (so I can't just add a whole `div` around it, as I want to keep other text visible all the time).

I want to use `getElementsByClassName` instead, but I can't seem to get it working.

```js
function showhide() {
   var div = document.getElementById("newpost");
   div.classList.toggle('hidden'); 
}
```

```css
.hidden{
    display : none;
}
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="showhide()">Click Me</button>
<span id="newpost" class="hidden"><p>text 1</p></span>
<span id="newpost" class="hidden">text 2</span>
<span id="newpost" class="hidden"><p>text 3</p></span>
```

Comment: An id should be unique.

Comment: What is `showhide` supposed to do? When you call it, what exactly do you want to change on the page? Do you want to toggle **all** the elements matching some criterion? Just one of them? (If so, which one?)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the comment.  For example, I want to hide the number in the sentence: "Today I went to 35 Brooklyn Ave", I want to add "35" inside `<span class="hidden">25</span>` so I can remove the number with a button.

Comment: Yes @KooiInc , I will remove the `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need *two* classes:

- one to designate the elements that you want to toggle (`hidable` in the example below)
- one to control whether an element is currently hidden (`hidden` in the example).

```js
function showhide() {
  for (var elem of document.getElementsByClassName("hidable"))
    elem.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showhide()">Click Me</button>
<span class="hidable hidden"><p>text 1</p></span>
<span class="hidable">text 2</span>
<span class="hidable hidden"><p>text 3</p></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you try to do this with getElementsByClassName the problem is if you access elements with classname and toogles the class first time it will remove that class and when you click again you are not supposed to access that class.
the possible solution would be two create two class name .hidden and .visible and add respective class onclick event or else you can also do it by accessing span tag directly

```
.hidden {
   display: none;
        }

<button id="button" onclick="showhide()">Click Me</button>

  <span class="hidden"><p>text 1</p></span>
  <span class="hidden">text 2</span>
  <span class="hidden"><p>text 3</p></span>

function showhide() {
   var spans = document.querySelectorAll("span");
   spans.forEach(function (span) {
   span.classList.toggle("hidden");
  });
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Thanks for the reply.  The answer works, but when I tested it with another text that had another `<span>` tag around it, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I would assign to each element whose display needs to be toggled a class such as `demo` that can be styled any way you want (except hidden) or not styled at all. I would then alternate adding or removing a class `hidden`:

```js
function toggle() {
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('demo');
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    element = elements.item(i);
    element.classList.toggle('hidden');
  }
}
```

```css
.demo {
    color: blue;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <p><input type="button" value="Toggle show/hide" onclick="toggle();"></p>
     <span class="demo">Line 1<br></span>
     <span class="demo">Line 2<br></span>
  </body>
</html>
```